# Docker error: client and server don't have same version

Tags: docker, boot2docker, docker-machine

Since I just updated Docker to 1.1.0 I get:

> Error response from daemon: client and server don't have same version (client : 1.13, server: 1.12)

Do you know how to fix this?

I switched back to 1.0.1 and everything works again.

Comment: I have the same problem, using ```boot2docker```. Is that also your case?

Comment: yes I'm also using boot2docker. after uninstalling docker and installing it again (not 'reinstall') its working again.
brew uninstall docker &&
brew install docker

Comment: Maybe you should edit the title / question to make it clear it is a ```boot2docker``` issue (for future reference).

Comment: Shameless plug: a friend and I put together a tool called [Docker Version Manager](https://github.com/rgbkrk/dvm) to help with this in the short term.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

It looks like you need to upgrade the VM after installing boot2docker:

> if you are upgrading from boot2docker 0.12 or later, you can update your existing virtual machine (after upgrading using the installer) using boot2docker stop && boot2docker download && boot2docker up - and you will not lose your existing data.

(https://github.com/boot2docker/osx-installer/releases/tag/v1.1.0)

Comment: also brew uninstall docker && brew install docker did the job

Comment: You no longer need to use the brew version of the docker command line tool. Boot2Docker provides the right version.

Comment: Having `An error occurred trying to connect: Get https://192.168.59.103:2376/v1.19/containers/json?all=1: x509: certificate is valid for 127.0.0.1, 10.0.2.15, not 192.168.59.103` :/

Comment: I ran into this certificate issue, too. I ran `boot2docker delete`, then `boot2docker init` and it started working.

Comment: A friend and I put together a tool called [Docker Version Manager](https://github.com/rgbkrk/dvm) to help with this in the short term.

Answer (score 19):

This can happen if you have updated Docker, but the service has not been restarted. You will then try to connect to the Docker daemon with the updated client, while the daemon (that was already running before the update) is still running the older version.

To fix this, restart the service:

sysV init:

`service docker restart`

systemd:

`systemctl daemon-reload`

`systemctl restart docker`

Comment: For `systemd` it is recommended to do `systemctl daemon-reload` before `systemctl restart docker`

Comment: Seems like the simplest answer is the best answer :)

Answer (score 13):

In case you use `docker-machine` to manage a local VirtualBox-based machines the solution is as simple as for boot2docker:

```
docker-machine upgrade MACHINE_NAME
```

It asks `docker-machine` to download the latest `boot2docker.iso` and place it as a new root filesystem in the upgraded VM.

By the way, the VirtualBox-backed docker machine has its root filesystem readonly. That mean it's not possible for any manual update survive the machine reboot. That was a surprise for me.

Answer (score 12):

I had the latest version of boot2docker, docker and virtual box but was still receiving this message. It seems running `brew upgrade boot2docker` isn't the best idea. When running `boot2docker upgrade`, I was asked to set a bunch of environment variables and then it worked for me.

Boot2docker asked me to set these (see the last lines):

```
$ boot2docker upgrade
Latest release for boot2docker/boot2docker is v1.3.0
Downloading boot2docker ISO image...
Success: downloaded https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/releases/download/v1.3.0/boot2docker.iso
    to /Users/.../.boot2docker/boot2docker.iso
Waiting for VM and Docker daemon to start...
.........oooooooooooooo
Started.
Writing /Users/.../.boot2docker/certs/boot2docker-vm/ca.pem
Writing /Users/.../.boot2docker/certs/boot2docker-vm/cert.pem
Writing /Users/.../.boot2docker/certs/boot2docker-vm/key.pem

To connect the Docker client to the Docker daemon, please set:
    export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.59.103:2376
    export DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/Users/.../.boot2docker/certs/boot2docker-vm
    export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
```

It's possible to cut and paste those three lines in one go, into your terminal.

To check they are correct:

```
$ env
```

Answer (score 11):

I was trying to query a Docker server with a more recent client:

- Server API version: 1.21
- Client API version 1.22

The solution for me was to just:

`export DOCKER_API_VERSION=1.21`

Reference:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cli/

Comment: Thanks! this fixed my problem

Comment: The fact that the docker protocol is versioned and backward compatible must not be well documented, or visible enough, given the amount of answers that (understandably) go to all sorts of length to upgrade docker in various scenarios...

Answer (score 3):

The correct answer here is very old *(Docker have renamed boot2docker to Docker Machine and added some more functionality to it)*.

Anyway I faced the same problem and took me about 3 days to fix :(

**Here's the solution**

1) find the location of the `boot2docker.iso`

```
sudo find ~/ -name 'boot2docker.iso'
```

2) delete the `boot2docker.iso` file, after taking a backup of it

```
/Users/{user}/.docker/machine/cache/boot2docker.iso
```

3) delete your docker vm

`docker-machine rm {default}`

this should delete that one as well:

```
/Users/{user}/.docker/machine/machines/default/boot2docker.iso
```

4) create new docker vm

```
docker-machine create --driver virtualbox default
```

this will download a new `boot2docker.iso` first and then use it to create your vm.

Now this should fix it :)

### **BUT**

> If you get any error here like:

```
Running pre-create checks...
(mega-docker) No default Boot2Docker ISO found locally, downloading the latest release...
Error with pre-create check: "Get https://api.github.com/repos/boot2docker/boot2docker/releases/latest: dial tcp: lookup api.github.com on 192.168.0.1:53: read udp 192.168.0.103:53947->192.168.0.1:53: i/o timeout"
```

try to download the `boot2docker.iso` file manually by going to https://api.github.com/repos/boot2docker/boot2docker/releases/latest then clicking on the `html_url` and finally choosing to download the file.

once you get the file go and place it manually in `/Users/{user}/.docker/machine/cache/`

finally re-run this command `docker-machine create --driver virtualbox default`

Answer (score 2):

The only thing that worked for me was killing the process and starting it with "sudo service docker start".

Answer (score 2):

The only thing the worked for me was removing the boot2docker image from VirtualBox then completely deleting `~/.boot2docker` folder, and finally running `boot2docker init` again.

Answer (score 1):

boot2docker delete

boot2docker init

worked for me. stop/start the deamon before and after that of course.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me: It just shuts the vm down, deletes & recreates it and starts it up again. It re-runs shellinit so your ENV variables get set with the correct IP address when it comes back up.

```
$ boot2docker poweroff && \
    boot2docker delete && \
    boot2docker init && \
    boot2docker up
$ eval `boot2docker shellinit`
```

Answer (score 0):

I find the version in brew is outdated compared to the one on the docker.io website. Therefore I think the best way is go to the website and download the install file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the latest version of boot2docker(v1.7.1) and got the client server mismatch error. Then I just ran `boot2docker upgrade` and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

### Ansible Answer:

If you came there by **Ansible** and not boot2docker, here is the solution: Use the `docker_api_version: auto` argument

```
- name: Mongo data container
  docker:
    docker_api_version: auto
    name: mongo-primary-dc
    image: debian:wheezy
    state: present
    volumes:
    - /data
```

I guess the reason is that the docker-py module used by Ansible is often not at the same version as the Ubuntu apt-get repository.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to do a Close > Power Off on the docker VM in VirtualBox, and then restart Kitematic. This fixed it for me.