# docker-swarm error: client and server don't have same version(client: 1.18, server: 1.17)

Tags: docker, boot2docker, docker-swarm

I have been experimenting to run docker swarm with machine. I am using virtualbox as provider. I am able to spawn three VMs and run them as swarm-master, swarm-node-00 and swarm-node-01. But I am not able to use my swarm cluster. Here are some additional info:

```
[peeyush@localhost swarm]$ docker-machine_linux-amd64 ls
NAME ACTIVE DRIVER STATE URL SWARM
dev virtualbox Running tcp://192.168.99.100:2376

swarm-master virtualbox Running tcp://192.168.99.101:2376 swarm-master (master)
swarm-node-00 virtualbox Running tcp://192.168.99.100:2376 swarm-master
swarm-node-01 * virtualbox Running tcp://192.168.99.102:2376 swarm-master
[peeyush@localhost swarm]$ eval "$(docker-machine_linux-amd64 env swarm-master)"
[peeyush@localhost swarm]$ docker info
FATA[0000] Error response from daemon: client and server don't have same version (client : 1.18, server: 1.17)

[peeyush@localhost swarm]$ docker version
Client version: 1.5.0-dev
Client API version: 1.18
Go version (client): go1.3.3
Git commit (client): 831c796
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
FATA[0000] Error response from daemon: client and server don't have same version (client : 1.18, server: 1.17)
```

Could you please help me figure out the issue here?

Answer (score 1):

Docker machine keeps a local copy of a boot2docker image under `~/.docker/machine/cache/`

You can upgrade this local copy running this command:

```
docker-machine upgrade
```

You can also force docker machine to use another boot2docker image using the parameter `--virtualbox-boot2docker-url`.

See the virtual-box driver documentation for more information: https://docs.docker.com/machine/#oracle-virtualbox

Comment: I have docker.io installed on Debian unstable but it gives `docker-machine: command not found`. The solution for me was https://stackoverflow.com/a/26578772/6702659